# Can a lambda safely return the address of a copied variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Given the following sample code:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    auto f = [=]()mutable->int*
    {
            return &i;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

1. g++ v.4.8.1 warns that "address of local variable ‘i’ returned".
2. Clang v.3.2 (MacOS's Clang) warns that "address of stack memory
   associated with local variable 'i' returned".
3. Neither VS2012 nor VS2013 RC warn of anything.

My understanding of lambdas is that the compiler will generate a functor class. That functor class will have members for all copied variables (`i` in the example). I believe that in the context of my code, as long as `f` exists, it is safe to return the address of one of its members. It seems to me that all compilers got it wrong. I think a warning about using the address of `f`'s member `i` after `f` goes out of scope is valid, but the warnings about the "local variable 'i'" are incorrect/misleading. Am I right?

Comment: You can make `i` `static`.

Comment: The functor class will have a reference to "i", but "i" is itself still just a local variable on the stack. Once main() returns, i no longer exists.

Comment: @joeking he is asking about the error, for example you don't get the same error with this code even though it's exactly the same: `struct S { int* operator()() { return &i; } int i; } f;`

Comment: @joeking Can you elaborate? He's capturing `i` by value (`[=]`), so why would it have a reference? Also, nobody is contesting that it's all out of scope after `main()` returns.

Comment: also i think this code has undefined behavior since you copy `i` without initializing it :(

Comment: My mistake WRT by-value.

Comment: Yes it looks like a compiler error, especially given that you can modify `i` in the lambda body and this modification will persist between the calls.

Comment: [expr.prim.lambda]/17 states "Every *id-expression* that is an odr-use (3.2) of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type." and has an example of taking the address of such an implicitly captured entity `N`, stating "`&N` points to the corresponding member of the closure type". (The implicit capture is described in /11.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The `&` operator is applying to the member, not the local object.

Demonstration is straightforward: just modify your example to output the addresses.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i;
    std::cout << & i << '\n';

    std::cout << [=]() mutable -> int * {
        return & i;
    } () << '\n';
}
```

http://ideone.com/OqsDyg

Incidentally, this compiles with no warnings under `-Wall` in GCC 4.9.

Comment: I'm very much inclined to believe you, as you have numerous great answers on C++ questions, but honestly some explanation or sources would be nice. I think we've all tried that example or something similar, but the big question is, how do we know we can rely on this behaviour?

Comment: @us2012 Don't know what I can add… the OP's belief about how it works is correct. The standardese which specifies lambdas is rather involved; I don't know how helpful it would be. Every use of a name from the surrounding local context is actually naming a functor member, and that member is either a reference or a copy. Some compilers apparently erroneously assume(d) it's a reference, but I suspect the error only goes as far as the message, because otherwise `mutable` would be broken.

Answer (score 4):

Some terminology:

- The `=` or `&` inside `[&](){ /*..*/ }` is called a *capture-default*.
- odr-use of a variable roughly means that the variable does not appear in a discarded-value-expression (such as `(void)some_variable` or `int x = some_variable, 5;`) and it doesn't occur in a constant expression.
- *compound-statement* is the "function block" `{` *statements* `}`
- the name of a variable is an *id-expression*

[expr.prim.lambda]/3

> The type of the *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the *closure type* — whose properties are described below.

/11

> If a *lambda-expression* has an associated *capture-default* and its *compound-statement* odr-uses (3.2) `this` or a variable with automatic storage duration and the odr-used entity is not explicitly captured, then the odr-used entity is said to be *implicitly captured*;

Therefore, `i` is implicitly captured.

/14

> An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is `=` or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an `&`. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type.

There is a non-static data member (of type `int`) in the closure type.

/17

> Every *id-expression* that is an odr-use (3.2) of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.

We don't even need to interpret this, as this paragraph provides us with an example very similar to the OP's:

```
void f(const int*);
void g() {
    const int N = 10;
    [=] {
        int arr[N]; // OK: not an odr-use, refers to automatic variable
        f(&N);      // OK: causes N to be captured; &N points to the
                    // corresponding member of the closure type
    };
}
```

If we apply this to the OP's example, we see that `&i` refers to the *internal* non-static data member of the closure type. Whether or not the diagnostic message is appropriate is not specified in the Standard ;)

Comment: [basic.scope.block]/1 says that "A variable declared at block scope is a *local variable*." Therefore, the OP's lambda does *not* return the address of a local variable.